# How to get ID of last row table to bind events to it?

Tags: jquery, events, datatable

what I want to do is to give every new row in my table validation functions , check All events for days and check time of drop down Lists
(from hour to hour) , so to do that I need the ID of the new Row as I did for old existed rows !
I'm stacked here , I tried many ways but always there's a bug in my code :
the table is a black box component owned by my company , I can read its scripts but I can't edit them . it has a bug and I have to deal with it .
the ids of cells is given by incrementing a counter .
so if we have 3 rows , ids of cells are :

```
 id    | task name    |  day    | from hour      | to hour
==============================================================
 id0   | task_name0   |  day0   | from_hour0     | to_hour0
----------------------------------------------------------
 id1   | task_name1   |  day1   | from_hour1     | to_hour1
----------------------------------------------------------
 id2   | task_name2   |  day2   | from_hour2     | to_hour2
```

and when you add a new row the ids of the new row are :

```
id4   | task_name4   |  day4   | from_hour4     | to_hour4
```

notice number 4 , it takes number of rows and assign it as an id .

the problem appears when you delete rows from the middle of the table 
that hidden input max_rows doesn't decrease and it mustn't to keep ids unique !

so , here's my problem I want to give events to the new ID which I have no idea what it is !! (this situation appears after deleting rows from the middle of the table ), 
my old way in doing that was to take number of rows and assign it to string like that : (this for check all days and uncheck all )

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#table_1_addRow').click(function()
        {

            var row=$('#table_1').find('tbody > tr').size();

            $('#col_task_days'+row+'_0').click(function(){
                for (var i=1;i<8;i++)
                {
                    //check all & make them readonly
                    if($('#col_task_days'+row+'_0').attr('checked')=='checked')
                    {
                        $('#col_task_days'+row+'_'+i).attr('checked','checked');
                        $('#col_task_days'+row+'_'+i).attr('disabled','disabled');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#col_task_days'+row+'_'+i).attr('disabled',false);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

this way failed !

I tried using another way 'last child ' but also it failed because check all was binded to two check all events one for itself and one for last child  !

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $('#table_1_addRow').click(function()
        {
             //days columns in the nine column in  table
            var id=$('#table_1').find('tbody > tr:last-child').children()[4].children[0].id;

            $('#'+id).click(function(){
                for (var i=1;i<8;i++)
                {

                        var id_son=$('#table_1').find('tbody > tr:last-child').children()[4].children[i].id;

                        //check all & make them readonly
                        if($('#'+id).attr('checked')=='checked')
                        {
                            $('#'+id_son).attr('checked','checked');
                            $('#'+id_son).attr('disabled','disabled');
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $('#'+id_son).attr('disabled',false);
                        }
                  }
          });
        });
    });
```

also it failed

can you suggest another ways ? 
hope I have declared my question !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [:last-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) CSS selector to get around this.

Check out the code snippet for more details.

```js
$(function(){
  $('table#grid').on('click', 'tr:last-child', function () {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
  });
});

// for binding to every row, you can just simply bind to 'tr' instead of 'tr:last-child' i.e.
//$(function(){
//  $('table#grid').on('click', 'tr', function () {
//    alert($(this).attr('id'));
//  });
//});
```

```css
table
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td
{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

tr:last-child
{
  cursor: pointer;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="grid">    
    <tr id='first'>
      <td>
        first
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr id='second'>
      <td>
        second
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr id='third'>
      <td>
        third
      </td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr id='fourth'>
      <td>
        Click on me - I should alert: 'fourth'
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why have you used this : find('td:last-child').parent(). I think that is not necessary. $(this).attr('id') seems enough.

Comment: yep , in that way , after saving the row you have to event binded to same id , one affect its td and another affect the last child as the code says , when click on ID check (last row) td .

Comment: yes yes i 100% agree `$(this).attr('id');` would be enough, infact i mentioned that also in my working example see, but i encounter little delay in mentioning that :)

Answer (score 0):

**Event Delegation** is the ultimate solution for old and new rows !

```
$("#table_1").on("click","tbody > tr > td[column=col_task_days] > input[type=checkbox]",function(event){
   console.log(event.target);
   var target = event.target;
   var currentCheckboxID = $(target).attr('id');
   if (!currentCheckboxID){
     return;
   }
   var isCheckAll = currentCheckboxID[currentCheckboxID.length-1] === '0';
   if (isCheckAll && $(target).is(":checked")){
        $(target).siblings("[type=checkbox]").attr("checked","checked");
        $(target).siblings("[type=checkbox]").attr("disabled","disabled");
   }else if (isCheckAll && !$(target).is(":checked")){
           $(target).siblings("[type=checkbox]").removeAttr("disabled");
   }

})
```